# Increase in Invalid Edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, edits

In the past 2 days, I've rejected about 20 invalid edits, in which the person actually **changed the asker's code** as their way of "answering." Actually, this is rather mind boggling to me, as this isn't even allowed on regular forums.

(EDIT: Turns out, many of those were "answer" edits, not "question" edits, my bad. Still, the problem is there, imho.)

I'm seriously wondering if there is more that can be done to provide guidelines for editing. I know that when you ask a question, there are rules on the side (which, aside, could stand to be expanded slightly). **Shouldn't there be something bright-blazingly obvious on the edit screen, defining what ISN'T a legitimate edit?**

(EDIT: What stands currently on the screen is rather "affirmative," so it doesn't make clear what NOT to do. For example: "Do not correct code errors on questions. Respond instead.")

Granted, there are still a lot of people who ignore the rules that are right in front of their faces, but at least it might reduce the problem. If the invalid edits continue to become more and more common, we're going to start seeing them slip past the edit review, and that would be VERY bad for SO as a resource.

Comment: `there are still a lot of people who ignore the rules that are right in front of their faces`: I think this is the biggest problem. You can put there anything you want, people don't read. And also is people who blindly approves/proposes anything that comes to that queue just to get a badge/points.

Comment: Here, this is pretty much what the edit screen looks like for edit-suggesters: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/252219/edit - note the rules/guidelines on the side.

Comment: Might want to make users whose edits were rejected too many times click through each bullet point in that screen before they edit again.

Comment: Well, I went back three days in your review history, and could only find two posts of the kind you described (where people are answering the question using code in suggested edits of other people's answers).  Both of them were unanimously rejected by the reviewers.  There were a few minor code corrections which you rejected but others approved; the code in these answers seemed to be obviously wrong (minor syntax errors, missing brackets, etc.), and the edits looked OK to me.

Comment: The reason I reject those, Robert, is that a single character can drastically alter a code. Thus, they change meaning. And I know there were more of the drastic nature anyhow.

Comment: Sure, I understand that.  Often, it can be hard to tell.  These posts seemed obvious.  Let me find an example.  Hold on.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4609786) was approved by three other people.  If three other people can agree that the code fix is correct, it (hopefully) is.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4575714) seems obvious... It is clearly an RGB calculation, but only the R variable is specified in the 3 terms.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4603274) also seems like an obvious correction.  Note that the other three reviewers all approved it.

Comment: Oh, wait, you're referring to edits to the the ANSWERS. I think that got lost on me for a moment. My original issue, however, still stands (albeit, edited).